# Implementing transactions with Collector for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-collector, data-quality

Currently I am looking into using ArcGIS Collector for field use.  I would like for there to be a QA process done before final submission. Is there a way to implement an approval process for the submissions similar to SQL transactions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting your own feature services from your own ArcGIS for Server, you can publish the feature services off a QAQC version instead of DEFAULT.

So, you would have:

```
DEFAULT version
--QAQC version
```

When you publish your feature services, you must make sure the data is pointed to the QAQC version.

This way when someone adds, removes, or updates features within the Collector app, the edits are being made to the QAQC version.

Then, someone in the office will verify the edits, and reconcile/post to the DEFAULT version.

Answer (score 0):

In 10.3 of ArcGIS Server you can use versioned data and Collector offline. Your field crew would create offline databases on their devices through Collector, then they would collect data and sync those changes back, now you wont see the data they have sync'ed back in a web map until the data has been reconciled.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/offline-maps-and-versioned-data.htm